# apciterator can't retrieve items after certain amount of time

Tags: php, caching, iterator, apc

**Update 06/23 **

At this point I was able to isolate the issue to a simple example. Firstly I store some example items:

```
apc_add('MY_APC_TESTA_1','1');
apc_add('MY_APC_TESTA_2','2');
apc_add('MY_APC_TESTA_3','3');
apc_add('MY_APC_TESTB_4','4');
apc_add('MY_APC_TESTB_5','5');
apc_add('MY_APC_TESTB_6','6');
```

Then I use APCIterator for retrieving the items, counting them with a foreach loop and additionally using getTotalCounts method of apciterator class for double checking.

```
$iterator = new APCIterator('user', '/^MY_APC/', APC_ITER_VALUE);

function showCache() {

    echo "keys in cache<br>-------------<br>";
    foreach ($items AS $key => $value) {
        echo $key . "<br>";
    }
}


$i = 0;    
foreach ($iterator as $current_item) {
        $i++;
}

echo 'getTotalCount: '.$iterator->getTotalCount().'<br>'; // output: 6
echo 'foreach count: '.$i.'<br>'; // output:  6

showCache();
```

Calling this script right after storing the items I am getting this output:

```
getTotalCount: 6
foreach count: 6
keys in cache
-------------
MY_APC_TESTA_1
MY_APC_TESTA_2
...
```

Calling this script couple of hours or a day later I receive this output:

```
getTotalCount: 6
foreach count: 0
keys in cache
-------------
```

So as you can see the iterator class can still retrieve the total count using its method getTotalCount but a foreach loop brings empty results although it was working a couple of hours earlier. That's the reason why my cache handlers are not working because they are using apciterator in conjunction with `apc_delete($iterator)` to get corresponding items and clear them once a modification was made. Since the foreach/array is empty there is nothing to delete. This is a huge problem. I don't assume that this is expected behavior. Any ideas how is this possible?

I am having the following setup on my VPS:

- CentOS 7
- Nginx with PHP-FPM
- PHP 5.4.16
- APC 3.1.13

APC Settings:

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  0
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  /tmp/apc.Z1n8dS
apc.num_files_hint  512
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    256M
apc.shm_strings_buffer  4M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 7200
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    7200
apc.write_lock  1
```

Comment: It seems like your regex doesn't match the remaining keys, what happens if you change it to: `new APCIterator('user', '/^resource\/schx_web\/.*/', APC_ITER_KEY);` ?

Comment: @Paradoxis This returns `bool(false)` and nothing gets deleted. However further debugging: the number `APCIterator::getTotalCount ` returns doesn't match the items that get deleted when using a foreach loop to iterate over the `$iterator ` variable. So the problem must be somewhere in here...

Comment: Try restarting your web server

Comment: The APC panel will list expired entries, which will really be deleted when you try to read them.. Perhaps the iterator automatically skips those? Have you tried dumping the value too?

Comment: @Paradoxis That didn't help either. I guess it really has to do with the discrepancy in the counts.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I can dump the values without any problems...

Comment: Have you tried apcu instead?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari same problem happened with apcu...the `apcIterator` just drops the entries after a certain amount of time. `getTotalCount` retrieves the correct number of items but when I run a foreach on the iterator it is empty...This usually happens after two or three hours...

Comment: After your last edit, I see the user cache ttl is 7200, and you say that the problem is shown *"a couple of hours or a day later"* ... So the iterator still sees the expired entries in the total count, and yet when you cycle through it, it'd skip them.. Yes, looks like a bug to me, or at least a lack of consistency.

Comment: Correct. I changed this value to 0 and now the problems are gone. However this is not the expected behavior of the apciterator class...so it is definitely a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APCIterator erroneously only returns cache entries that are younger than apc.ttl, but it includes these in the number returned by getTotalCount().

I've submitted a pull request for this bug here: https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/pull/253